# .IndexOf(char variable), how to get the next value after the character

Tags: c#, methods, indexof

`tag.IndexOf('>')` , ok so this returns an integer.

I want the second address so after the character sign
so if '>' is at address 8 I want address 9.

How can I do that?

Comment: What's wrong with `tag.IndexOf('>') + 1`?

Comment: just add `1` to the index ...

Comment: Given: _____; I expect: ______.  Please edit your question with some test cases.

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with

```
tag.IndexOf('>') + 1
```

Comment: it doesnt work , gives an error, i mean how is this possible anyway to add a integer to a character?

Comment: You are adding an integer to the index not the character

Comment: `tag.IndexOf` returns integer. Where is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something?

```
int address = tag.IndexOf('>') + 1;
```

Comment: i m sorry guys don t know whats happening to me today i was adding it along with the character since i have a huge string line i didnt notice

Answer (score 2):

If you want the next character after `>`, assuming that tag is a string, then you need to do this:

```
int index = tag.IndexOf('>') + 1;
char nextChar = '';
if(index < tag.Length)
     nextChar = tag[index];
```

You need to make sure that the index is not out of range of the string length. Otherwise, it will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's only courteous to explain why you downvote. This is the only answer that fully answers the question.

Comment: i m sorry guys don t know whats happening to me today i was adding it along with the character since i have a huge string line i didnt notice

Answer (score 0):

You don't specified what exactly to find after the found character (I expect you are searching for something...)
If searching for EVERY occurance of a single character in the string you could do something like this:

```
string s = "  >   > ";
int i=-1;
while (i<s.Length) {
    i=s.IndexOf('>', ++i);
    if (i<0) break;
    // For every occurance in s, do something here...
}
```